# Assigning pair of integers

Tags: algorithm

how to solve this problem:

We are given N pairs of integers. For each pair of integers, we have to assign one integer to A and the other to B, such that the difference between the sum of integers assigned to A and the sum of integers assigned to B is minimum.

I can't think of anything better than O(2^N).

I thought of greedy but it doesn't always give the optimal result.

Comment: it's not homework.I encountered this problem while solving a problem on interviewstreet.com

Comment: Branch and Bound would work, since you can calculate in advance the "biggest possible adjustment you can still make" and prune a subtree if even the biggest adjustment would keep the current attempt worse than the best solution found so far. And you could set the initial best to the result of the greedy algorithm. Doesn't improve the Big Oh though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform the problem into this:

Given: a sequence of non-negative integers (the absolute difference between the original pairs)
Problem: Partition the integers into two sets so as to minimize the absolute difference of the sums of the elements of each subset.

This is the [Balanced Partition Problem](http://chinmaylokesh.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/balanced-partition-problem-finding-the-minimized-sum-between-two-partitions-of-a-set-of-positive-integers/) which is NP-complete. The two problems are equivalent; that is, you can transform the Balanced Partition Problem into your problem: associate, for each element n<sub>i</sub> of the sequence, the integer pair (n<sub>i</sub>, 0). Thus, you aren't going to do better than O(2<sup>N</sup>).

<strike>Problem: assign a sign (plus/minus) to each integer such that the absolute value of the sum of the sequence is minimal.</strike>

I suspect<sup>*</sup> that if you first sort the sequence in descending order, then a greedy algorithm will give optimal results. This will be an O(N log N) algorithm.

(<sup>*</sup>) If I'm wrong, please post a counter-example.

Comment: Can you prove/give guidelines to proof why it gives optimal solution? I am still not certain why greedy approach will do :|

Comment: @amit - I don't have a proof at hand. It's just a hunch. The idea is that later elements of the sequence can only make smaller changes to the sum.

Comment: _the sum of the sequence is minimal_ and *positive*, if not we assign only minus signs to get the lowest sum

Comment: let the array of sorted differences be `arr=[8,7,5,5,5]`, then greedy will assign `8-7-5+5-5=-4`, while optimal is `8+7-5-5-5`

Comment: It smells like a partition problem variation on the absolute value of the differences, and the greedy approach is not exact.

Answer (score 0):

Let the pairs be (A_0,B_0),...,(A_n,B_n). Let D_i = |A_i-B_i|. Then your problem is equivalent to choosing signs for the D_i to minimize the sum, which is equivalent to finding a subset of the D_i which sum to half the total sum, which is equivalent to subset-sum, which is NP-complete. So you won't do better than 2^n.

Except: if the numbers are small, you can try a dynamic programming approach: DP[i][n] is true iff you can choose a subset summing to n using D_0,..,D_i. You start with DP[0][0] being true, and then DP[i+1][n] is true iff DP[i][n] was true or DP[i][n-D[i+1]] is true.
This solution is O(n*(the maximum possible sum))